# Using Contact Form 7 via WP REST API

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, wp-api

Having little access to the server on this external site, I have used WordPress and the WP REST API v2 to pull in content that is, of course, managed on WordPress. Works great!

I have been able to post Contact Form 7 data from this external site to this WordPress site and it does send an email, but the form has no validation and on the post-it returns this error.

```
{
    "code": "rest_cannot_edit",
    "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to edit this post.",
    "data": {
    "status": 401
}
}
```

It is posting to the page https://www.flambang.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/1666?_=1498600326410#wpcf7-f11791-o1 and it is strange that it even works - meaning that it sends the email and adds contact data to the DB.

Has anyone used Contact Form 7 with data that is delivered via JSON via and the WP REST API? Are there other endpoints I can use?

thanks,

Paul

Comment: Brother have you solved this problem? I'm trying to use the contact form through the REST API and I'm not finding content to support me! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

user one of method to auth in wordpress like:**JWT**, **AuthBasic** ..

1. find proper plugin like authbasic or jwt authantication ..
2. setup and after send reqeust

Comment: this answer is not useful, please consider improving it with actual code examples and useful links